# HttpUrlConnection taking exactly 2 minutes for timeout

Tags: httpurlconnection, connection-timeout

Whenever the URL is trying to load, it takes larger than the time set in the connection timeout, but setting the connection timeout to 20 seconds does not work it happens only after 2 minutes, and also whatever the time that is set in the connection time out, its taking exactly 2 minutes for the server to connection time out.

```
URL urlConnect = new URL(url.toString());
HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnect.openConnection();
urlc.setDoInput(true);
urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 20); // Timeout is in MILLI seconds
urlc.connect();
```

Or whether the 2 minutes is the default values for timeout? how to set the timeout to exactly 20 seconds. It doesnot have any redirect urls or anythings its a plain url. Why is it taking exactly 2 minutes for the connection to timeout?